# Type casting in Java. Double to long

Tags: java, typecasting-operator

Why the output of `System.out.println((long)Math.pow(2,63));` and         `System.out.println((long)(Math.pow(2,63)-1));` is same in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output is the same because `double` does not have enough bits to represent 2<sup>63</sup> exactly.

*Mantissa* of a `double` has only 52 bits:[image]

This gives you at most 17 decimal digit precision. The value you computed, on the other hand, is 9223372036854775808, so it needs 19 digits to be represented exactly. As the result, the actual representation of 2<sup>63</sup> is 9223372036854776000:

- Mantissa is set to 1.0 (1 in front is implied)
- Exponent is set to 1086 (1024 is implicitly subtracted to yield 63)

The mantissa of representation of `1` is the same, while the exponent is 1024 for the effective value of zero, i.e. the exponents of the two numbers differ by 63, which is more than the size of the mantissa.

Subtraction of 1 happens while your number is represented as `double`. Since the magnitude of minuend is much larger than that of the subtrahend, the whole subtraction operation is ignored.

You would get the same result after subtracting much larger numbers - all the way to 512, which is 2<sup>9</sup> ([demo](http://ideone.com/lG6phU)). After that the difference in exponent would be less than 52, so you would start getting different results.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.pow( double, double )` returns a `double` values.

`double` in java is a 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point.(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

If you look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format you will find, that this format is composed of:

- 1 bit sign
- 11 bit exponent
- 53 bit significant precision

The returned number by `pow` would need a higher precision (63) to be stored exactly.

Basically the `1` you add is below this precision threshold.

In contrast long has 64 bit precision.

To make it more clear lets assume we are working in decimal and not in base2:

In some imaginary small float datatype with a precision of `2` the value 1000 would be stored as `1.00e3`. If you add 1 it would have to store it as 1.001e3. But since we only have a precision of 2 it can only store `1.00e3` and nothing changes. So `1.00e3 + 1 == 1.00e3`

The same happens in your example, only that we are dealing with larger numbers and base2 of cause.

Comment: Thanks for the simpler language :)

Comment: You're welcome. I find it difficult myself to imagine this in base2.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parenthesis to incorporate the result and then subtract 1, like this:

```
    System.out.println((long)Math.pow(2,63));

    System.out.println(((long)(Math.pow(2,63))-1));
```

Output:

> 9223372036854775807
>
> 9223372036854775806

Answer (score -1):

For long data type in java,Maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). (2^63 -1)

So Even if you try

```
System.out.println((long)Math.pow(2,65));
System.out.println((long)(Math.pow(2,63)-1));
```

output

```
9223372036854775807
9223372036854775807
```